# Operator overloading with integer template parameter specialization

Tags: c++, templates, integer, operator-overloading

I have a vector class defined as follows:

```
template <unsigned int SIZE>
class Vector : public Stringable
{
    private:

        float mData [SIZE];

    public:
        Vector ();

        ...
};
```

I have also declared some operators (outside of the Vector class) on this (mathematical) vector:

```
template <unsigned int SIZE>
Vector<SIZE> operator+ (const Vector<SIZE>& vec, float c);

template<>
Vector<3> operator+ (const Vector<3>& vec, float c);

template<>
Vector<4> operator+ (const Vector<4>& vec, float c);

template <unsigned int SIZE>
Vector<SIZE> operator+ (const Vector<SIZE>& vec1, const Vector<SIZE>& vec2);

template <>
Vector<3> operator+ (const Vector<3>& vec1, const Vector<3>& vec2);

template <>
Vector<4> operator+ (const Vector<4>& vec1, const Vector<4>& vec2);
```

This is how they are implemented:

```
template <unsigned int SIZE>
Vector<SIZE> operator+(const Vector<SIZE>& vec1, const Vector<SIZE>& vec2)
{
    Vector<SIZE> result = Vector<SIZE>(vec1);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; (i + 4) < SIZE; i += 4)
    {
        __m128 lhs = _mm_set_ps(vec1[i], vec1[i+1], vec1[i+2], vec1[i+3]);
        __m128 rhs = _mm_set_ps(vec2[i], vec2[i+1], vec2[i+2], vec2[i+3]);
        _mm_add_ps(lhs, rhs);
        _mm_store_ps(result.getRawData(), lhs);
    }

    for (; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        result[i] = vec1[i] - vec2[i];
    }

    return result;
}

template<>
Vector<3> operator+<3>(const Vector<3>& vec1, const Vector<3>& vec2)
{
    Vector<3> result = Vector<3>(vec1);
    float tmpBuffer [4];

    __m128 lhs = _mm_set_ps(vec1[0], vec1[1], vec1[2], 0);
    __m128 rhs = _mm_set_ps(vec2[0], vec2[1], vec2[2], 0);
    _mm_add_ps(lhs, rhs);
    _mm_store_ps(tmpBuffer, lhs);
    mempcpy(result.getRawData(), tmpBuffer, 3 * sizeof(float));

    return result;
}

template<>
Vector<4> operator+<4>(const Vector<4>& vec1, const Vector<4>& vec2)
{
    Vector<4> result = Vector<4>(vec1);

    __m128 lhs = _mm_set_ps(vec1[0], vec1[1], vec1[2], vec1[3]);
    __m128 rhs = _mm_set_ps(vec2[0], vec2[1], vec2[2], vec1[3]);
    _mm_add_ps(lhs, rhs);
    _mm_store_ps(result.getRawData(), lhs);

    return result;
}

template <unsigned int SIZE>
Vector<SIZE> operator+(const Vector<SIZE>& vec, float c)
{
    Vector<SIZE> result = Vector<SIZE>(vec);

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; (i + 4) < SIZE; i += 4)
    {
        __m128 lhs = _mm_set_ps(vec[i], vec[i+1], vec[i+2], vec[i+3]);
        __m128 rhs = _mm_set1_ps(c);
        _mm_add_ps(lhs, rhs);
        _mm_store_ps(result.getRawData(), lhs);
    }

    for (; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        result[i] = vec[i] + c;
    }

    return result;
}

template <>
Vector<3> operator+<3>(const Vector<3>& vec, float c)
{
    Vector<3> result = Vector<3>(vec);
    float tmpBuffer [4];

    __m128 lhs = _mm_set_ps(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2], 0);
    __m128 rhs = _mm_set1_ps(c);
    _mm_add_ps(lhs, rhs);
    _mm_store_ps(tmpBuffer, lhs);
    mempcpy(result.getRawData(), tmpBuffer, 3 * sizeof(float));

    return result;
}

template <>
Vector<4> operator+<4>(const Vector<4>& vec, float c)
{
    Vector<4> result = Vector<4>(vec);

    __m128 lhs = _mm_set_ps(vec[0], vec[1], vec[2], 0);
    __m128 rhs = _mm_set1_ps(c);
    _mm_add_ps(lhs, rhs);
    _mm_store_ps(result.getRawData(), lhs);

    return result;
}
```

All of the above code is in a single file: "Vector.cpp"

I'm currently in the process of moving from 'normal' vector operations to SIMD operations using Intel's SSE Intrinsics.

Since vectors with size 3 & 4 are quite common in my application, I'd like to specialize my template operators for those, to allow for better use of XMM registers. (As you can see, the SIMD loop won't be used for any vector with a size < 4).

Unfortunately, I'm at a loss on how to actually accomplish this, I don't really know what declarations/definitions I need, what the template parameters need to be,...

**Edit:** Right now, I'm getting a 'Multiple Definitions' linker error, I'm using clang++ 5.0

There's about 50 of these errors (a lot, 50 is just a guess-timation), all of the specializations seem to be present...

```
CMakeFiles/Space.elf.dir/src/Entities/Entity.cpp.o: In function `Maths::Vector<3u> Maths::operator+<3u>(Maths::Vector<3u> const&, float)':
/home/.../CLionProjects/Space/src/Maths/Vector.cpp:427: multiple definition of `Maths::Vector<3u> Maths::operator+<3u>(Maths::Vector<3u> const&, float)'
CMakeFiles/Space.elf.dir/src/main.cpp.o:/home/.../CLionProjects/Space/src/Maths/Vector.cpp:427: first defined here
CMakeFiles/Space.elf.dir/src/Entities/Entity.cpp.o: In function `Maths::Vector<4u> Maths::operator+<4u>(Maths::Vector<4u> const&, Maths::Vector<4u> const&)':
/home/.../CLionProjects/Space/src/Maths/Vector.cpp:392: multiple definition of `Maths::Vector<4u> Maths::operator+<4u>(Maths::Vector<4u> const&, Maths::Vector<4u> const&)'
CMakeFiles/Space.elf.dir/src/main.cpp.o:/home/.../CLionProjects/Space/src/Maths/Vector.cpp:392: first defined here
/home/.../CLionProjects/Space/src/Maths/Vector.cpp:377: multiple definition of `Maths::Vector<3u> Maths::operator+<3u>(Maths::Vector<3u> const&, Maths::Vector<3u> const&)'
CMakeFiles/Space.elf.dir/src/main.cpp.o:/home/.../CLionProjects/Space/src/Maths/Vector.cpp:377: first defined here
CMakeFiles/Space.elf.dir/src/Entities/EntityManager.cpp.o: In function `Maths::Vector<3u> Maths::operator+<3u>(Maths::Vector<3u> const&, float)':
```

I've censored out part of the paths, but you get the Idea

Comment: Is there a header file Vector.h? I think all template definitions must be in a header.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem, and here's how.
I separated definitions and declarations as you normally would for any other class.
Then at the bottom of my implementation file (.cpp) I explicitly instantiated not just my classes, but also ALL of my operators.

(Unfortunately the amount of loading/unloading made SIMD instructions obsolete because ot created more overhead than it got rid of. Specializing the full class might be a solution here, but that's for another time)